# Using avconv with os.system to create timelapse

Tags: raspbian, python

I wanted to create some timelapse footage with my NOIR pi and IR light source with my pi 2 B+. I am able to capture the photos fine. My problem is that when is use `os.system("avconv........")` to convert the photos to video I keep getting a syntax error.

When I paste the same line (minus the `os.system` and `""`) it works absolutely fine. I have `import os` and `import sys` at the top of my script so it isn't that it can't call `os.system` (I don't think).

I have also tried `subprocess.call`w but have the same issue. Both attempts are below. I'm less familiar with `subprocess.call` so am even more uncertain as to whether it's correct.

```
subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/avconv","-r","24","-i","/home/pi/Timelapse/image%05d.jpg","-b","3000k","-r","24","-c:v","mpeg4",TimelapseVideo.mp4])

os.system('avconv -y -r %s -i /home/pi/Timelapse/image%s.jpg -r %s -vcodec libx264 -q:v 3 -vf crop=4256:2832,scale=iw:iw /home/pi/Timelapse/timelapse.mp4" %(FPS_IN,'{:05d}',FPS_OUT))
```

I'm fairly new to python, I only started playing with it a few weeks ago when I got the pi, steep learning curve. Any advice would be fantastic :)

Answer (score 2):

In the first case you need to quote `TimelapseVideo.mp4`

```
subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/avconv","-r","24","-i","/home/pi/Timelapse/image%05d.jpg","-b","3000k","-r","24","-c:v","mpeg4","TimelapseVideo.mp4"])
```

In the second case you are mixing single and double quotes. I suggesting suing [format strings](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#formatstrings) instead of the format operator `%`.

```
os.system('avconv -y -r {0} -i /home/pi/Timelapse/image{{:05d}}.jpg -r {1} -vcodec libx264 -q:v 3 -vf crop=4256:2832,scale=iw:iw /home/pi/Timelapse/timelapse.mp4'.format( FPS_IN,FPS_OUT)
```

Note that `{{` and `}}` are needed if you want a curly brace in a format string.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am still getting errors with both lines. I feel like it must be something in the avconv bit but I have no idea what.  sudo python SleepingTimeLapse.py
  File "SleepingTimeLapse.py", line 60
    os.system('avconv -y -r {0} -i /home/pi/Timelapse.image{{:05d}}.jpg -r {1} -vcodec libx264 -crf 20 -g 15 timelapsevideo.mp4 /home/pi/timelapse.mp4' .(FPS_IN,FPS_OUT))
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You are missing`format` after the string.